# sscanf not detecting zeros

Tags: c, project

I'm having a hard time using sscanf to scan hour and minutes from a list. Below is a small snip of the list.

```
1604 124 12:05p 1:21p Daily
1605 124 1:20p 2:40p Daily
1606 173 3:15p 4:38p Daily
1607 173 4:20p 5:43p Daily
1608 124 8:20p 10:00p Daily
1609 124 9:00p 10:37p Daily
1610 173 8:40a 10:05a Daily
1611 124 10:50p 12:20a Daily
1701 17 9:25a 1:00p Daily
1702 17 10:10a 1:45p Daily
1703 86 1:55p 5:15p Daily
1704 86 2:30p 5:50p Daily
1711 17 10:40a 2:15p 5
1712 86 3:10p 6:30p 1
1731 48 6:25a 9:30a 156
1732 100 10:15a 1:30p Daily
1733 6 2:15p 3:39p Daily
```

I've tried this, but for some of the time it is dropping the zero, which is very important.(I'm putting this information into structures).

```
    put_flights_into_array(int size){

      int i,check_enter,x,c;

      check_enter=0;
      x=0;

      /*Puts the temp_flights to all_flights*/

      for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(temp_flights[i] == '\n'){
          all_flights[check_enter][x]='\0';
          check_enter++;
          x=0;
        }else{
          all_flights[check_enter][x]=temp_flights[i];
          x++;
        }
      }

      /*Puts all_routes into proper structures*/

      for(i=0;i<check_enter;i++){
        sscanf(all_flights[i],
        "%d %d %d:%d%c %d:%d%c %s",
        &all_flights_divid[i].flight_number,
        &all_flights_divid[i].route_id,
        &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_hour,
        &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_minute,
        &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_format,
        &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_hour,
        &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_minute,
        &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_format,
        &all_flights_divid[i].frequency);
        }
```

This is how I declared my structure.

```
struct all_flights{
  int flight_number;
  int route_id;
  int departure_time_hour;
  int departure_time_minute;
  char departure_time_format;
  int arrival_time_hour;
  int arrival_time_minute;
  char arrival_time_format;
  char frequency[10];
};
struct all_flights all_flights_divid[3000];
```

These are the results I get. Notice how at 1604 the time is 12 5, it should be 12 05, What happen to the zero before the five? Also same thing happen at 1609, the first zero disappeared.

```
1604 124 12 5 p 1 21 p Daily
1605 124 1 20 p 2 40 p Daily
1606 173 3 15 p 4 38 p Daily
1607 173 4 20 p 5 43 p Daily
1608 124 8 20 p 10 0 p Daily
1609 124 9 0 p 10 37 p Daily
1610 173 8 40 a 10 5 a Daily
1611 124 10 50 p 12 20 a Daily
1701 17 9 25 a 1 0 p Daily
1702 17 10 10 a 1 45 p Daily
1703 86 1 55 p 5 15 p Daily
1704 86 2 30 p 5 50 p Daily
1711 17 10 40 a 2 15 p 5
1712 86 3 10 p 6 30 p 1
1731 48 6 25 a 9 30 a 156
1732 100 10 15 a 1 30 p Daily
1733 6 2 15 p 3 39 p Daily
```

Comment: Only the middle section is code. The rest is just data that I'm trying to compare.

Comment: `int`s don't store leading zeros - I guess your printing function is just not printing it correctly.

Comment: oh right int don't print zeros... Thanks a lot.

Comment: `int` is a fixed size, so it stores leading 0 bits if the number is smaller (nearer zero) than 2^n/2.   The answer by dldnh explains that you don't see leading zero's because of the printf format you've likely used. By default printf doesn't print leading zero's, you have to ask for that using an appropriate format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem isn't with the scanning, it's with the printing. if you use a format like this

```
printf("%02d", n);
```

that zero will make sure there is a leading zero like you want

Comment: Thank you. We always talk about this in class, but had no use for it until now. This actually solved two of my problems. I love Stackoverflow, especially the people on it!